# ASP.NET web services and Blackberry -- need assistance with returning complex data

Tags: xml, json, blackberry, data-transfer

I need to transfer a significant amount of structured data that goes something like this in XML -

```
<person>
    <fname></fname>
    <lname></lname>
    <DOB></DOB>
    .
    .
</person>
```

Each `person` record has 5 fields, and each time the app is opened, about 30-40 (possibly more) `person` records will be loaded.

Will XML be a good implementation to do this? Should I be worried about Data rates over 3G / Processor speed / Code and memory size?

Should I be looking at JSON? If so, can I make an ASP.NET web service return JSON data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my experience it has been very easy doing JSON parsing (and generation) in BlackBerry using the  http://www.json.org/java/org.json.me.zip code, which works great and has a very small footprint.  If you do want to go the XML route, check out  http://kxml.sourceforge.net/ as I've seen it mentioned here on Stack Overflow before in regards to BlackBerry XML parsing.

Comment: I'm worried about the data size though. I've tested the Web service and it returns an XML that's ~20kb.

I'm wondering if it'll induce too much latency in Downloading / parsing/ displaying?

Comment: 20kb transfers pretty quickly over a 3G connection, and the JSON library itself is pretty efficient with memory and CPU (in my experience).  However if the total latency for download, parsing, and displaying is more than a second or two it would probably be a good idea to show some sort of "spinner" UI to show the user that something is going on...